# IntelliJ Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to use an Eclipse project with IntelliJ. In Eclipse, the project has a jar in its build path, which wraps a manifest file containing a Class-Path entry with multiple other jars.

[image]

While Eclipse detects the jars in the manifest and uses them for the class path, IntelliJ throws compile errors. Is there a way to get IntelliJ scanning the manifest file of a jar and inherit the dependencies?

[image]

As you can see in this picture, all jars are inherited from the class-path of jbossall-client.jar.

In IntelliJ only the wrapper jar is used as a dependency:

[image]

jbossall-client.jar/META_INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: JBoss Inc.
Class-Path: commons-logging.jar concurrent.jar ejb3-persistence.jar hi
 bernate-annotations.jar hibernate-commons-annotations.jar...
```

Comment: Put jar files to WEB-INF\lib or using Manven, Gradle when transfer from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Add an Application Server rather than add the jar as a dependency `CTRL` + `ALT` + 'S' or `File -> Settings` and Application Server

Comment: I've had better luck in InteliJ when used `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate a maven project and then import that instead of the Eclipse project files.

Comment: @KennethClark I am using the Community Edition

Comment: @MichaelShopsin I want the projects to be linked, almost everyone develops with eclipse here.

Comment: If you're using `maven` for your builds then the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command should be in sync with your Eclipse project. I'm recommending the command only because IntelliJ tends to like the results better.